# Wordpress Queries Not Working?

Tags: wp-query, loop, sidebar

```
//Display All Reviews
function display_all_reviews( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'tag', 'reviews' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'display_all_reviews' );

//Movie All Reviews
function display_movie_reviews( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'tag', 'movie-reviews' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'display_movie_reviews' );
```

`Display All Reviews` is the only thing that is suppose to be displayed on the homepage and `display_movie_reviews` is suppose to be displayed in the sidebar for its category `is_category('movies')`, as well as posts in that category. I see they have `$query->is_home()` but I have tried `is_category('movies')` without any luck..

Here is the `display_movies_reviews` markup for the category:

```
<div id="sidebar-reviews">
    <span>Movie Reviews</span>
    <ul>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'display_movie_reviews' ); ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'sidebar-reviews', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>

</div>
```

And here is the `display_movies_reviews` markup for the posts within the movies category:

```
<!-- ###Movies Single Sidebar### -->
<?php elseif ( ! empty ( $GLOBALS['post'] ) && is_single() && in_category( 'movies', $GLOBALS['post'] ) ) : ?>
<div class="sidebar-ad">
</div>
<div id="sidebar-reviews">
    <span>Movie Reviews</span>
    <ul>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'display_movie_reviews' ); ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'sidebar-reviews', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>

</div>
```

I have tried fixing it like this:

```
//Movie All Reviews
function display_movie_reviews( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_category('movies') ) {
        $query->set( 'tag', 'movie-reviews' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'display_movie_reviews' );
```

but havent had any luck.  Any ideas how I can get the homepage and sidebar working?

**edit: sidebar**

```
<?php if ( $query->is_category('movies') ): ?>
<?php $movies = new Wp_Query('tag=movie-reviews'); ?>

<?php while ( $movies->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php $movies->the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'sidebar-reviews', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Wow. Shouldn't you be using new WP-Queries for everything? It would be a trillion times easier.

Comment: @DanGayle what do you mean?

Comment: For the sidebar, just use a wp-query block. See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sidebar bit, you should be using a new `Wp_Query`:

```
if ( $query->is_category('movies') ):
    $movies = new Wp_Query('tag=movie-reviews');

    while ( $movies->have_posts() ) :
        $movies->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'sidebar-reviews', get_post_format() );
    endwhile;

    else:
        get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' );
endif;
```

You don't need query filters for anything except the main loop on a page.

Comment: I edited my main post and added the code after seeing this post but I'm getting an error... did I do it incorrectly?

Comment: the error is `Fatal error: Call to a member function is_category() on a non-object in /home/dev/public_html/wp-content/themes/wgtc/sidebar.php on line 52`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test any of that code. You'll need to update the if statement accordingly.